# Divide a integer and get decimal answer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math

i currently have an integer `int i` and its value is `60` i wish to divide this by `100` to get 0.60 but i cannot do this please help

```
int i = 60;
int x = 60 / 100; // Dosen't work should be 0.60 instead returns 0
```

Comment: An Integer is.. well an Integer. You cannot get fractions with it. If you must (for some unknown reason) only use integers, you can use mod (%) to get the rest of the division... in your case: int x =60%100 and x should be 60 (rest of the division)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the correct value using the following method:

```
float x = 60 / 100.0f;
```

If you are looking for the value 0.60 you cannot assign it to an integer (whole number) type.

Answer (score 9):

divide by 100.0f and return result into a float.

Comment: C will promote i to float to do the division since other part is a float.

Comment: Looks like i is already an integer (code in above question)? You could do "float i2 = i" which will upconvert int i to a float i2. You can do an explicit cast, which would do same but be more explicit "float i2 = (float)i;"

Comment: Little known tidbit for extra credit - apparently objective-c assumes floating point literals such as xx.yy are double by default and not float. So, you can be explicit and use xx.yyf to override this.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 60;
float x = (float)i/100.0f;
NSLog(@"%.2lf", x);
//this will print 0.60
```